# Capistrano: "cap deploy" doesn't take effect when deploying a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am deploying my rails application using Capistrano.
Once I have made changes to my app I do "cap deploy" and it seems working properly, but changes don't take effect. I always have to do "cap deploy:stop" and "cap deploy:start" and then everything is fine.
So I guess it has to do with "cap deploy:restart" which is run when deploying changes.

here is my deploy.rb: [deploy.rb gist](https://gist.github.com/2017169)

Hope that someone can help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you do a complete deploy and pipe the output to a log, like: ``cap deploy > deploy.log 2>&1``

Comment: @PizzaPill here it is: [deploy.log](https://gist.github.com/2017379)

Answer (score 1):

If you restart unicorn using the `USR2` signal it doesn't automatically know the correct environment for bundler. Check out this gist (specially the **before_exec** block) and adjust your unicorn config accordingly.

https://gist.github.com/534668

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed in line (105) in your gist

```
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  if File.exist?("/tmp/unicorn.example.pid")
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.example.pid`"
  end
end
```

that you are testing for the pid file existence on your local machine. Instead you should do that on your server. Try changing it to

```
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "test -f /tmp/unicorn.example.pid && kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.example.pid`"
end
```

But remember that it still fails silently if the pid file is missing.

Comment: are you sure that this is checking the file existence on my local machine? cause I just got that deploy.rb from [this tutorial](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn) and thought it would be all fine...

Comment: I did that change but I still have to do cap deploy:stop and cap deploy:start :(

Comment: Can you try to run it directly on the server pls? 

kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.example.pid`

Comment: I did `kill -s USR2 cat /tmp/unicorn.example.pid` and it returns `-bash: kill: cat: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: /tmp/unicorn.example.pid: arguments must be process or job IDs`

Comment: Please add the quotes around `cat /tmp/unicorn.example.pid` as on the answer. Doing quoting correct is hard as a comment here.

Comment: @illtempo sorry, been some time. i did not see your last reply. I did it with the quotes but I don't get any output.

Comment: Please make sure you are using back ticks. I don't know if we are on the wrong track. Can you check that '''/tmp/unicorn.example.pid''' actually exists on the server?